# Trying to get unsold lots

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

My code is this, but I'm having an issue getting unsold lots. I don't want to input an int for lotNumber, because I want to show all unsold lots.

Where did I go wrong?

```
public ArrayList<Lot> getUnsold()
{  
   for(Lot lot : lots) 
   {
    Bid highestBid = lot.getHighestBid();
    lotNumber = lot.getNumber();
    Unsold = new ArrayList<Lot>();
      if (highestBid != null) 
        {

            System.out.println("Lot number " + lotNumber + " is sold"); //retuern "Sold" is highestBid
        }
      else
        {
            System.out.println(lotNumber); //print bidder and highest bid value
        }
   }
   return Unsold;
}
```

Comment: where is `lots` initialised? Should it be passed in as a parameter?

Comment: lots is in ArrayList<Lot>.

Comment: I know the type, that's obvious from the for-each loop, I was just pointing out that it isn't initialised or passed in to the method. See @Rp-'s answer, where they have assumed you meant to pass it in!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `Unsold` (should be unsold) before the for loop. And you are not adding anything to the `Unsold` list in `else` block. You need add that lot to `Unsold` in `else` block.

```
//assuming you are passing `lots` as parameter
    public List<Lot> getUnsold(List<Lot> lots)
    {  
       List<Lot> unsold = new ArrayList<Lot>();
       for(Lot lot : lots) 
       {
        Bid highestBid = lot.getHighestBid();
        lotNumber = lot.getNumber();
          if (highestBid != null) 
            {

                System.out.println("Lot number " + lotNumber + " is sold"); //retuern "Sold" is highestBid
            }
          else
            {
                System.out.println(lotNumber); //print bidder and highest bid value
                unsold.add(lot); // you are missing this
            }
       }
       return unsold;
    }
```